# How to get the revision count for file in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

Using templates, I want to find out how many times a file has been revised across all changesets. So, put another way, how many changesets feature that file.
Is there a way to do it? And can it be done with the Keywords extension?

And yes, I realise it's not really what Mercurial is about. I have sucky requirements:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a normal feature of an VCS to track, when a file was changed, just run `hg log THE_FILENAME` to see all changesets which affect one specific file.

To count them, run for example `hg log THE_FILENAME | grep -c "^changeset"`.

Comment: Thanks, that works. How about a way to do it within a template rather than grepping the output?
I need to embed the number within the file.

Answer (score 5):

`hg log -q filename | wc -l` will output amount of changesets

Answer (score 3):

I thought I'd just add one more option to the list here since grep and wc (word count) may not be available in your console (Windows users especially). There is an equivalent functionality in PowerShell:

`hg log -q filename | Measure-Object`

This will return the count by default (and as you can see there are other options you can play with using [Measure-Object](http://ss64.com/ps/measure-object.html))

```
Count    : 14
Average  :
Sum      :
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property :
```

And if you are interested in how many commits you have done for the entire repository you can omit the -q filename parameter:

`hg log | Measure-Object`

```
Count    : 492
Average  :
Sum      :
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property :
```